# Can I pass a string into a function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

How can I pass a string from an array into a function?
I want to pass a string such as `"Battleship"` into the function `print()` and have it print `"Where would you like to place the Battleship?"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char ship_names);

int main (void)
{
    int index = 0;
    char ships_name[5][21]= { "Aircraft Carrier (5)", "Battleship (4)", "Submarine (3)", 
                              "Cruiser (3)", "Destroyer (2)"};

    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        print(*ships_name[index]);

return 0;
}

void print(char ship_names)
{
    printf("Where would you like to place the %s?\n", ship_names);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `print` take a `char const *` instead of a single `char`. Then, drop the `*` from the call:

```
print(ships_name[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your print function take a pointer to character, not character. That is because in C, a string is just a memory location containing some characters terminated by a null byte.

You should change the signature of print to

```
void print(char *ship_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of dereferencing the pointer to the shipsname[index] string, you should pass the string pointer itself with `print(ships_name[index])` which passes a pointer to the string. Your method will then have to take a char *.